# Qt SQLite Обращение к результатам select'а через названия полей

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

Сейчас моё обращение к БД выглядит так:

```
   QVector<QStringList> VectorOfRecords;

        QueryConstructor SelectAll;
        SelectAll.setTableName(QStringLiteral("TableName"));
        SelectAll.setOrderByClause("Id", Descending);

        QSqlQuery getRecordsQuery(Database);

        if( getRecordsQuery.exec(SelectAll.constructSelectQuery()))
        {
            while (getRecordsQuery.next())
            {
                QStringList Row;
                for (int i = 0;i < 9;i++)
                {
                    Row.push_back(getRecordsQuery.value(i).toString());
                }
                VectorOfRecords.push_back(Row);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            QMessageBox::critical(NULL, QObject::tr("Error"), getRecordsQuery.lastError().text());
        }
```

QueryConstructor это мой класс, в данном примере он составляет запрос на вывод всей таблицы целиком.

Я хочу тут заменить это

```
getRecordsQuery.value(i)
```

на обращение не по индексу, а по названию. Потому что по циферкам обращаться как-то ненадежно и нечитаемо, мне кажется. Как это можно сделать? Так-то все работает, но хочется сделать более гибкую систему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Я хочу тут заменить это

Посмотрите [`QVariant QSqlQuery::value(const QString &name) const`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#value-1) - это перегруженный вариант. То, что вам надо.

Comment: Прям настолько близко было?) Даже смешно. Спасибо